# visual code intellisense node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS code 1.10 but the intellisense is not always working as I would expect.

For instance, I'm require a module('simple-hl7') which I've installed locally with NPM.
This module has properly been added to my package.json as a dependency.

With ATA I would have expect intellisense function out-of-the-box.

is there something I'm missing?

In the screenshot below I would have expect `addsegment` function to be poped-up in the intellisense pop-up

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQvZ2.png)

Comment: Had VS Code ever prompted you to install any plugins?

Comment: not that I remember, which plugins should VS code asked me to install?

Comment: Maybe this one? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=leizongmin.node-module-intellisense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work on JS/TS support for VSCode. Here's the chain of events that I believe triggers this bug:

1. There are no typings (`d.ts` files) published for simple-hl7, or at least they are not published under `@types/simple-hl7`
2. Because no typings exist, our IntelliSense picks up the Typings from the js files. Here's the definition it uses:

   [image]
3. This definition causes TypeScript to mistakenly think that the `Message` constructor takes zero arguments.
4. Therefore, passing in any arguments to the constructor triggers this bug: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13032
5. That bug causes `msg` to have an `any` type. This is why you don't see any suggestions on it

One workaround would be to create a `d.ts` file simple-hl7. We're also looking into the constructor resolution issue and hopefully will get that fixed soon.